# python 3.x kivy: dynamically adding widgets to scrollview

Tags: python, kivy

I´m new to kivy and trying to create a scrollview that gets filled with several widgets live. That kind of works.. 
BUT the line items themselves often loose their own widgets and I often get this error:

**[CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute**

I read a lot of "clock", blocking the mainthread etc.. I tried to resolve it by using a different thread.. but still widgets are missing.

Attached the code and a picture. help is very much appreciated!! thx!

[widgets missing..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctt2Q.png)

my controller.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0

<Controller>:

    size_hint: 1., 1.
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False


    tab1_pgbar: tab1_pgbar
    layout_content: layout_content
    tab1_refresh_btn: tab1_refresh_btn

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab1
        text: 'Browse'

        BoxLayout:
            id: bl
            orientation: 'vertical'

            ScrollView:
                size_hint: 1.0,0.7              

                GridLayout:
                    id: layout_content
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height                
                    cols: 1
                    row_default_height: '100dp'
                    row_force_default: True
                    spacing: 0, 5            

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1.0,None
                height: 25              

                ProgressBar:
                    size_hint: 1.0,1.0  
                    id: tab1_pgbar 
                    max: 1000

                Button:
                    id: tab1_refresh_btn    
                    text: 'Refresh'             
                    size: 100,25
                    on_release: root.refresh()
```

my kivyMain.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import mainthread

import time
import threading


class myJobEntry(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myJobEntry, self).__init__()       


    def addStuff(self,runindex,program):   
        b1 = Button(text=runindex,size_hint=(None,1.0),width=100)
        b2 = TextInput(text=program,height=80)

        hbox1 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')      
        for i in range(10):
            hbox1.add_widget(Button(text='{}'.format(i)))


        vbox1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        vbox1.add_widget(hbox1)
        vbox1.add_widget(b2)

        self.add_widget(b1)
        self.add_widget(vbox1)


class Controller(TabbedPanel):
    '''Create a controller that receives a custom widget from the kv lang file.
    Add an action to be called from the kv lang file.
    '''    
    layout_content = ObjectProperty()
    tab1_refresh_btn = ObjectProperty()
    tab1_pgbar = ObjectProperty() 
    text_input = ObjectProperty() 

    def addSeveralObjects(self):
        self.tab1_pgbar.value = 0
        self.layout_content.enabled=False

        for i in range(100):              
            myObj = myJobEntry()
            myObj.addStuff('{}'.format(i),'i')            
            self.layout_content.add_widget(myObj)                            
            self.updateBar()


    def refresh(self):        
        self.tab1_refresh_btn.enabled = False
        self.tab1_pgbar.value = 1        

        mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.addSeveralObjects)
        mythread.start()        

        self.resetRefreshButton()


    def resetRefreshButton(self):
        self.tab1_refresh_btn.text = 'Last Refresh: {}'.format(time.ctime())
        self.tab1_refresh_btn.enabled = True


    def updateBar(self):
        self.tab1_pgbar.value += 1

class ControllerApp(App):

    def build(self):       
        return Controller()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ControllerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is your thread, a better option is to use the kivy Clock object:

```
...
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.metrics import dp
...

class Controller(TabbedPanel):
    '''Create a controller that receives a custom widget from the kv lang file.
    Add an action to be called from the kv lang file.
    '''
    layout_content = ObjectProperty()
    tab1_refresh_btn = ObjectProperty()
    tab1_pgbar = ObjectProperty()
    text_input = ObjectProperty()
    i = 0
    h = NumericProperty(0)

    def addSeveralObjects(self, *args):
        self.layout_content.enabled = False
        myObj = myJobEntry()
        myObj.addStuff('{}'.format(self.i), '{}'.format(self.i))
        self.layout_content.add_widget(myObj)
        if self.i % 4 == 0:
            self.h += dp(420)
        self.updateBar()
        self.i += 1
        if self.i >= 100:
            self.clock.cancel()

    def refresh(self):
        self.tab1_refresh_btn.enabled = False
        self.clock =Clock.schedule_interval(self.addSeveralObjects, .05)
        self.resetRefreshButton()

    def resetRefreshButton(self):
        self.tab1_refresh_btn.text = 'Last Refresh: {}'.format(time.ctime())
        self.tab1_refresh_btn.enabled = True

    def updateBar(self):
        self.tab1_pgbar.value += 1
...
```

In your kv:

```
<Controller>:
    ...
    TabbedPanelItem:
        ...
        BoxLayout:
            ...
            ScrollView:
                size_hint: 1.0,0.7
                GridLayout:
                    id: layout_content
                    height: root.h
                    size_hint_y: None
                    cols: 1
                    row_default_height: '100dp'
                    row_force_default: True
                    spacing: 0, 5
            ...
        ...
     ...
 ...
```

Comment: cool. that works better, thanks! but still the mainthread seems to be blocked and all of the 100 items appear at once (at the end)
any idea how to "see" line items appear live and progress bar updating?